# modify auth code of laravel 5 as per my list of requirements

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a old database on which I want to use new Laravel 5.2, i want to change its User Authentication code to my requirements like - its tablename, username field(its not a email field), its password and also need to stop laravel from encrypting the password as the password are not encrypted in the database, also I need to remove features like remember me option, register new users ... Can anyone please help/guide me.

password from users and database are one and the same - laravel shall not encrypt the password string.

I am trying to succeed in all the above things together past 2 days now. if one thing is rectify I goof up with another. specially in case of password checking - currently any / wrong password will also be allowed as a user - only username needs to be correct.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using **AuthController** class that Laravel provides, your user model class is called **User** and you're using **Eloquent** user provider as it's the default one.

In order to change the name of the table that stores users you need add the following to your **User** class:

```
protected $table = 'your_table';
```

If you want to change the column that is used to login users from email to another column, you need to add the following code to your **AuthController**:

```
protected $username = 'username';
```

Registration won't be available to your users if you don't define routes for those actions so no need to disable that.

In order to disable remember-me functionality you need to override **setRememberToken()** of your **User** model and make it empty. This way remember-me token won't be saved for that user which will prevent user from logging-in automatically:

```
public setRememberToken() {}
```

Comment: Thanx jedrzej.kurylo, I also need laravel NOT to check for hashed password. as of now I have solved that problem by editing the core file itself of eloquentuserdriver in laravel framwork.

Comment: It is possible, but it is a really bad practice to store unencrypted passwords. Can't you just hash the existing passwords?